# Button enabled from jQuery is disabled after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, telerik

I am using an asp button and a telerik radcombobox in my asp page and the button is initially disabled from mark-up. When the user select an item from the radcombobox, then the OnClientSelectedIndexChanged event will fire and there I am enabling the button. But once its enabled and I click the button, it is again disabled after postback.

```
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbModel" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" Width="100%"
    EmptyMessage="Select Model" Height="120px" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Model 1" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Model 2" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" Enabled="false" />
```

Script:

```
function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged() {
  $('#<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').prop("disabled", false);
}
```

which is the best way that I can make the button enabled after postback?

Comment: Whats wrong with `SelectedIndexChanged`? Enable button on server side. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-server-side-selectedindexchanged.html

Comment: @Satpal I need it from Client side, so I am using the OnClientSelectedIndexChanged event instead of the server side SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: Then use a hidden field/local storage to store the state(enabled/disabled) of button. Then set its state on page load.

Comment: where this function defined?

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution for your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put an update panel over your Add  Button.

Answer (score -1):

keep the javascrit code and do Same work on post back, in the code behind, check the item of the racombobox, if its changed enable your button.

```
btnAdd.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep the JavaScript and RadComboBox markup the same and remove the `Enabled="false"` code from the button's markup.  In the page's server-side `Page_Load` event, set the button's `Enabled` property based on whether or not a value has been selected:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnAdd.Enabled = (rcbModel.SelectedIndex > -1);
    //...
}
```

When the RadComboBox's empty message text is displayed, in your case "Select Model", the `SelectedIndex` value will be -1.

Comment: Downvoter: next time, tell me now I can improve my answer. Also, try to answer the question yourself, and try voting on other answers, and also try voting on the question. Solid effort.